# Mysql select query does not return the exact result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named User, Holiday.
Now my objective is to search user.
I need to search a user by the name from user table or city from the holiday table.
If I search by name, then Name from user table and his city from holiday table should be display. And if I search by city then city from holiday table and his Name from user table should be displayed.

User table::
[image]

Holiday Table
[image]

I have tried the following::

```
          SELECT * FROM `holiday`,`user` 
          WHERE holiday.UserID=user.UserID 
                and user.Name like '%Bre%' 
                or holiday.City like '%Bre%'
```

But :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like you to use LEFT JOIN,

```
  SELECT user.Name,holiday.City FROM  `user` LEFT JOIN `holiday`
                  ON user.UserID  =holiday.UserID
                        WHERE (user.Name like '%Bre%' 
                        or holiday.City like '%Bre%')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. This query returns only row having city name with 'Bre'. But just look at the user id 4 from the user table. The name of the user is "Breter". But his userId not present in holiday table. thats why its not showing. But I need to show this also.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `select *` because there are some columns have the same name in two tables, such as UserID.

Try this:

```
SELECT `user`.userID, `user`.Name, `holiday`.city 
FROM `holiday`,`user` 
WHERE holiday.UserID=user.UserID 
      and user.Name like '%Bre%' 
      or holiday.City like '%Bre%'
```

Comment: ok, sorry, I just found the problem is "where ... and ... or", you should use "(user.Name like '%Bre%' or holiday.City like '%Bre%')"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
      SELECT * FROM `user` left join `holiday` on holiday.UserID=user.UserID 
      WHERE user.Name like '%Bre%' 
            or holiday.City like '%Bre%'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. This query returns only row having city name with 'Bre'. But just look at the user id 4 from the user table. The name of the user is "Breter". But his userId not present in holiday table. thats why its not showing. But I need to show this also.

Comment: @Rounak really, it must be `left join` in your case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `holiday` h
LEFT JOIN 
 `user` u
ON 
  h.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE
  u.Name like '%Bre%' or h.City like '%Bre%'
```

Notice, that given your tables no result is returned.

Comment: thanks for the reply. This query returns only row having city name with 'Bre'. But just look at the user id 4 from the user table. The name of the user is "Breter". But his userId not present in holiday table. thats why its not showing. But I need to show this also.